# How to dispose an unmanaged resource/object that doesn't implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, google-sheets-api, dispose

Actually question is simple but I wanted to provide as much information as possible to help everyone to understand problem/issue. For this reason question may seem long/hard.

My question is briefly: how to dispose/destroy an unmanaged resource/object that doesn't implement IDisposable interface.

I'm getting data from Google Spreadsheet by requesting (executing) query. Sometimes data which is retrieved could be really large (i.e. 1.5-2 GB) and it's being loaded into directly memory. The retrieved data comes as JSON format and automatically deserialized to Spreadsheet object type like [in this line](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/b84a95825355615c3ef1e9d8d0d5bd25471a901a/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.cs#L7564)

I cannot dispose this object completely from memory since this is an unmanaged resource (doesn't implement `IDisposable`).

I've taken couple of images of memory consumption during execution (retrieval of data from Google Spreadsheet API).
There are three phases;

- Before execution,
- Right after execution and during of manipulation the object,
- After disposing (calling GC to clean up).

For instance if I try to get a Spreadsheet object;

- In the first phase memory state is 53 MB,
- In the second phase, after execution completes (just 1 line of code, `request.Execute()`, loads the object into memory in 1.st block of code.) As shown below, memory state is 1.7 GB.
- In the third phase, after calling GarbageCollector for clean up, memory state is 405 MB

[image: Memory consumption graph between phases]

As it's seen in the above memory graph as well there is a memory leak which is about 350 MB that I cannot free by using traditional ways. In the second phase I'm manipulating this raw data to convert into human readable format to show user on GUI. The data I'm obtaining after manipulation could be only 1-2 MB not more. But 350 MB of useless data is lost somewhere of memory.

So far I have searched;

- GarbageCollector working principle and disposing implementations
- IDisposable and tried as it's shown 6.th code block and it cannot dispose the object completely if I use it with a using block. This only can dispose most of it but not all of it as I described it as three phases in above figure.
- C# pointers (and could't implement for this scenario)
- [SafeHandle and it's derived types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=net-6.0) This is a really deep-dive topic and is hard to understand for me.

  - First, I've created a Spreadsheet wrapper for manage this unmanaged resource as I wrote in the 2.nd block of code
  - Second, I've created, and special SafeHandle class in the 3.rd block of code. This inherits from `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid` (implements `IDisposable`) and calls `ReleaseHandle()` automatically when `_sdSheetSafeHandle.Dispose()` is called inside "`SpreadSheetResponse`" wrapper class.
  - Third (I think this is the core issue/place I'm got stuck), I've tried to import `CloseHandle` WinAPI and use it in a static class call as NativeMethod. As far as my understanding this releases unmanaged object based on given IntPtr object. But I don't know how to convert/get an object of pointer as `IntPtr`.
  - Forth, I've tried to get IntPtr (or pointer by '&') by "ToIntPtr" extension that is present in `ObjectHandleExtensions` from `SpreadSheet` object to be able to set in 3.rd block of code as SetHandle (responseHandle). But I'm getting some error in 3.rd block code when executing `return NativeMethod.CloseHandle(handle)` also shown in the below figure.

[image: Error message when disposing object.]

So if I summarize the question; How can I dispose this Spreadsheet object to free the memory after I'm done with it. According to my research, the best options is to use SafeHandle method but I couldn't implement it. Can you give me a roadmap to overcome this issue?

1.

```
private static void ExecuteGetQuery()
{
    SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = _SheetService.Spreadsheets.Get(_GoogleSpreadSheetIdentifier);

    request.IncludeGridData = true;
    // here is first phase, before execution
    using (SpreadSheetResponse response = new SpreadSheetResponse(request.Execute()))
    {
        //Console.Write(response.GoogleSpreadSheet.Properties.Title);
        // Here is second phase, after getting data from Google Sheet and manipulating data to convert human-readable form to show user on GUI.
    }
    // Here is third phase, which is response object must be properly disposed to free memory. 
}
```

2. 

```
public class SpreadSheetResponse : IDisposable
{
    private SpreadSheetSafeHandle _sdSheetSafeHandle;
    private Spreadsheet? _sdSheet;
    public Spreadsheet? GoogleSpreadSheet => _sdSheet;
    public SpreadSheetResponse(Spreadsheet response)
    {
        _sdSheet = response;
        _sdSheetSafeHandle = new SpreadSheetSafeHandle(response.ToIntPtr());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_sdSheetSafeHandle != null && !_sdSheetSafeHandle.IsInvalid)
        {
            // Free the handle
            _sdSheetSafeHandle.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

3. 

```
internal class SpreadSheetSafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    public SpreadSheetSafeHandle(IntPtr responseHandle) : base(true)
    {
        SetHandle(responseHandle);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return NativeMethod.CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

4. 

```
internal static class NativeMethod
{
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    //[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    internal extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    //[System.CLSCompliant(false)]
    //public static explicit operator IntPtr(void* value);
}
```

5. 

```
public static class ObjectHandleExtensions
{
    public static IntPtr ToIntPtr(this Spreadsheet target)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            //Spreadsheet* sheet_pointer = &target;
            return (IntPtr)(&target);
        }
    }
}
```

6. 

```
public class SpreadSheetResponse : IDisposable
{
    public readonly SpreadSheetResponseType ResponseType;
    public Spreadsheet? SdSheet => _sdSheet;
    private Spreadsheet? _sdSheet;
    public SpreadSheetResponse(SpreadSheetResponseType type, Spreadsheet response)
    {
        ResponseType = type;
        this._sdSheet= response;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._sdSheet = null;
        GC.Collect(3, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"As it's seen in the above memory graph as well there is a memory leak which is about 350 MB"_ - I would argue that this can not be seen at the graph.  Have you tried performing operation several times (like 20-30)? Also note 1) runtime does not "free" all the memory as soon as it becomes "useless" 2) there is LOH which should be taken in consideration - it is not compacted by default for perfromance reasons which can seem to be a "memory leak".

Comment: To check for potential LOH "issue" you can try calling something like `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce; GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Aggressive, true, true);`

Comment: How do you know it's unmanaged? Unless it's a COM object it's probably managed and the memory will be freed eventually. In certain circumstances it may also be possible to free COM objects early. Your whole code which messes around with `IntPtr` and `CloseHandle` doesn't make sense: it's not a WINAPI handle you can free, it's just an object.

Comment: @GuruStron  "__I would argue that this can not be seen at the graph.__" I'm new to .NET. Alright, you might right but this is the only option that I can understand whether there is a leak or not. "__Have you tried performing operation several times.__" Yes I have and every time it happens same. Memory usage is reducing by time but really slow. Alright i think got the LOH issue but cannot i still remove it?

BTW, I cannot use GCCollectionMode.Aggressive option since I'm using .NET 6.0 it's not available in it. And i tried forced instead and didn't work.

Comment: @Charlieface  "__How do you know it's unmanaged?__" If it's not then why it is not disposed immediately after out of scope of using block. And Doesn't managed objects implements IDispoable?  Yes it will be freed evetually but the point is taht app is going to run users local machine and needs to be freed not to consume much memory.  "__it's not a WINAPI handle you can free.__" OK now i got what that API is used for.  So isn't there any other way to get around handling memory issues directly like in C++?

Comment: "If it's not then why it is not disposed immediately after out of scope of using block" because GC doesn't free things immediately. "Doesn't managed objects implements IDispoable?" only when they wrap an unmanaged handle. "isn't there any other way to get around handling memory issues directly" no. GC will free memory dependent on system memory pressue automatically. You don't need to do anything. The only time is when the app has generated huge amounts of LOH, and then perhaps you could force a GC, but beyond that you are wasting your time.

Comment: @Charlieface  Alright, I think I understand now. The key point that helped me is "GC will free memory dependent on system memory pressue automatically" So if I'd give an solid example like following for this would be correct ?: Let's say for a the moment, OS have available free 2 GB memory at this point if I run app and allocates 1.5 GB of memory and 500 MB of 1.5 GB is useless.  And another app is opened and requested 1 GB memory  then due to memory pressure in the previous app(.NET app) GC releases that 500 MB redundant object(s) to open free area for newly opened application.

Comment: Yes that's correct. You might want to compact the LOH as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=net-7.0 Eitehr way, that whole code involving `SafeHandle` should be removed, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Charlieface Alright thank you very much for your effort. I appreciate that. You can post the explanation I will accept it also if you'd give an solid example like I did would be awesome. Now I understand that I didnt get GC working principle correct. A solid example may help future visitors to help them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255176/discussion-between-livan3li-and-charlieface).